# NOSQL Database for

Tags: nosql

can anybody say me if I use NOSQL database and then kind of database should I use for development of a salary benchmarking website like glassdoor? Should that be MongoDB or Neo4j database, which is best for my web application? Can anybody suggest me... I would appriciate any type of answers ... :)

Comment: Hi grv.giit, this is a very broad question so [doesn't suit this site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) :)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably start by reading up on some of the basics. Google is a good aid. Good words to search for would be for example Big Data, Hadoop or RavenDB. I barely know the basics myself, but basically NOSQL typically refers to a non-relational, file-based database system built on clusters of drives.

NOSQL solutions such as Hadoop are used when the system requires the use of much more data than a typical relational database can handle. Like, if you're talking about terabytes as opposed to gigabytes, this might be something to go for.

I'll leave any further advice to the people who actually know and use those systems, but as I said, if you need to ask what NOSQL is, I would encourage to read up on the basics first. There are plenty of easy-to-understand examples available in google. After that, you might get a better idea about how to ask about the specifics of what you need advice on.

Here's what Wikipedia has to say about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

Comment: Neo4j is relational via aggregate contrasted with relational via sets